# Identifying the version of the grammar with Antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Is there a good way to have Antlr4 identify the version of a grammar used to parse input?

If I have two grammars, GA and GB, where GA is a subset of GB where GB imports GA is there a way to have Antlr4 report if the parsed input was parsed using GA or GB?

I could simply try parsing it with GB first and if that failed try parsing it with GA but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to have Antlr keep track of what rules where used and say, "I successfully parsed this but only used rules from the GA grammar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right approach would be to correlate each rule (or only key rules) to a parser version.

First of all you are going to need a field to track current version:

```
@members {
    int currentVersion = 1;
}
```

Now, let's suppose you have a rule `RULE_ONE` which correlates with version *one* and RULE_TWO which correlates with version *two*.
Each time a rule correlated with a higher version is accepted the `currentVersion` field should be changed:

```
RULE_ONE
      {currentVersion = Math.max(1, currentVersion);} //1 is the parser version
    : some_token
    ;

RULE_TWO
      {currentVersion = Math.max(2, currentVersion);} //2 is the parser version
    : some_token
    ;
```

Thus, when parsing is done, you can get the maximum version which has been used.

Comment: Question here - if I am writing the input file that gets parsed by this file, how do I say, "parse this with version 1"?  I hope there is a way to embed this into the input file, and not just have to slam it into a script.

Comment: @TonyEnnis, try [Semantic predicates](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md). E.g.`RULE_ONE: {version1}? expr ;`

Comment: @TonyEnnis, P.S. Once you've detected grammar version of an input file, set `currentVersion` to a proper value. And then validate rules using predicates.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking, but [in my MySQL grammar](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLParser.g4#L114) I have to support multiple server versions, which I do by using semantic predicates. That means, I can use a single grammar and enable/disable certain paths depending on a `serverVersion` field I have in my parser. This is how it looks like:

```
alterDatabase:
    DATABASE_SYMBOL schemaRef (
        createDatabaseOption+
        | {serverVersion < 80000}? UPGRADE_SYMBOL DATA_SYMBOL DIRECTORY_SYMBOL NAME_SYMBOL
    )
;
```

and works very well. I can use this approach even in [the lexer](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLLexer.g4#L354) (but there with validating semantic predicates, for performance reasons), which allows me to switch keywords on and off, like this:

```
CONTRIBUTORS_SYMBOL: C O N T R I B U T O R S {serverVersion < 50700}?;
```